# If variable "A" (value from a file) equals variable "B" (SPECIFIC value from PHP generated table), set a group of new variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to use "greenlight.png" on the image in the **corresponding table row only** if the row value matches the value from my local file. I'm getting the **$live_link** value via:

```
<?php
$live_link_file = 'PIProjectSwitcher/live_link.php';
$f = fopen($live_link_file, 'r');
if ($f) {
$live_link = fread($f, filesize($live_link_file));
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

My PHP table is generated via:

```
<table width="700" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0" style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: small; text-align: center;"><td width="660" height="35" align="left" valign="middle">Package Name</td><td width="40" height="35">Live</td><td width="40" height="35">Ready</td><td width="40" height="35">Edit Mode</td></tr>
<?php     
if ($insight_packages_list = opendir('Insight_Packages/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($insight_packages_list))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && $entry != "Blank-Package") {
        echo "<tr valign=\"middle\">
        <div class=\"floatleft\"><td height=\"25\" style=\"font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: large;\">{$entry}</div></td>
        <td height=\"25\" align=\"center\">
        <a href=\"http://firestar/ProjectInsight/create_insight_package_live_link.php?entry=$entry\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to load the $entry package into the BAM? Y/N?')\"><img src=\"images/$live$ready\" class=\"floatcenter\" width=\"25px\" height=\"25px\" id=\"$entry\" name=\"$entry\" /></a></td>
        <td height=\"25\" align=\"center\"><img src=\"images/$live$ready\" class=\"floatcenter\" width=\"25px\" height=\"25px\" /></td>
        <td height=\"25\" align=\"center\">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>";
            }
    }
    closedir($insight_packages_list);
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The final result looks like:
[image]

The table results are looking at my local directory and one of those directories will always match the value from the **live_link.php** file.

**I'm hoping there's a way to set a group of variables and apply them to that specific matching table row, but I don't know how to do that.**

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if ($live_link == $entry) {
$live = 'greenlight.png';
$ready = 'greylight.png';
$editmode = 'locked.png';
} else {
$live = '';
$ready = '';
$editmode = '';
}

if ($live_link != $entry) {
$live = 'greylight.png';
$ready = 'greenlight.png';
$editmode = 'locked.png';
} else {
$live = '';
$ready = '';
$editmode = '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

The error you got may have had to do with the heredoc echo `echo <<<EOT` 
PHP does not want to see anything else on the line after ending EOT;  and it must start in column one of the line. Depend on your PHP rev.
[PHP Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
The code below is untested.  I put a lot of effort to make your code more elegant. 
I added a few things from my standard PHP/HTML page template.

The `height` attribute of `<td>` is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
`td{height:25px;text-align:center;}`

I don't think this is needed: `<div class="floatleft">`
I added `text-align:left` to the CSS

`<img>` width and height do not have a px suffix.

When the are no PHP errors, the next thing to do is check your HTML an CSS with the W3C validators.
[W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)
[W3C CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)  
I also highly recommend these performance checkers:
[GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com/)
[Google PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/)
This one has every detail of were every millisecond of page load went.
[enter link description here](https://www.webpagetest.org/)

You have an anchor in the last column and the the `<td></td>` looks blank.  IKadded the word Edit. 
I do not like GET links.  I much prefer POST.  This is how I do links in a table cell.

```
<td><form action="http://firestar/ProjectInsight/create_insight_package_live_link.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="entry" value="$file" /><button>Edit</button></form><td>
```

And the new updated code.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1800');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PI Project Switcher</title>
<style>
table width:700px;border: 1px solid black;>

td{height:25px;text-align:center;font 400 1em Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; }
.large{font-size:1.2em;}
.small{font-size:.8em;background-color:#E0E0E0;}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<title>PI Project Switcher</title>
<table><tr class="small"><td style="width:660px; height:35px; text-align:left; valign:middle;">Package Name</td><td style="width:40px height:35px;">Live</td><td style="width:40px height35px;">Ready</td><td style="width:40px height35px;">Edit Mode</td></tr>
EOT;
​$live_link = file_get_contents('./PIProjectSwitcher/live_link.php');
foreach(glob("./Insight_Packages/*.*") as $file){
  if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $entry == "Blank-Package"){continue;}
  $equal = 0;
  if ($live_link = $file) {$equal = 1;}
  echo <<< EOT
  <tr valign="middle">
  <td class="large">$file</td>
  <td><a href="http://firestar/ProjectInsight/create_insight_package_live_link.php?entry=$file" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to load the $file package into the BAM? Y/N?')"><img src="./images/$live[$equal]" width="25" height="25" id="$file" name="$file" />Edit</a></td>
  <td style="height:25px;text-align:center;"><img src="./images/$ready[$equal]" class="floatcenter" width="25px" height="25" /></td>
  <td style="height:25px;text-align:center;"><img src="./images/$editmode[$equal]" class="floatcenter" width="25" height="25" /></td></tr>
</table>
EOT;
}
?>
```

---

End of Update

---

Let's start here:

Replace this:

```
<?php
$live_link_file = 'PIProjectSwitcher/live_link.php';
$f = fopen($live_link_file, 'r');
if ($f) {
$live_link = fread($f, filesize($live_link_file));
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

with this:

```
$live_link = file_get_contents('./PIProjectSwitcher/live_link.php');
```

And clean up the output code.

```
foreach(glob("./Insight_Packages/*.*") as $file){
  if $file == '.' || $file == '..' || $entry == "Blank-Package"){continue;}
  $equal = 0;
  if ($live_link = $file) {$equal = 1;}
  echo <<< EOT"<tr valign="middle">
  <div class="floatleft"><td height="25" style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: large;">{$file}</div></td>
  <td height="25" align="center">
  <a href="http://firestar/ProjectInsight/create_insight_package_live_link.php?entry=$file" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to load the $file package into the BAM? Y/N?')"><img src="images/$live$ready" class="floatcenter" width="25px" height="25px" id="$file" name="$file" /></a></td>
  <td height="25" align="center"><img src="images/$live$ready" class="floatcenter" width="25px" height="25px" /></td>
  <td height="25" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>";
  EOT;
  }
```

Select the .png's based on $equal

Define these arrays before the loop
Where the array outputs [not equal value,equal value]

```
$live = array('greylight.png','greenlight.png');
$ready = array('greenlight.png','greylight.png');
$editmode = array('locked.png','locked.png');
```

Add this near the top of the loop

```
$equal = 0;
if ($live_link = $file) {$equal = 1;}
```

Then in the loop

```
  echo <tr><td>$live[$equal]</td><td> $ready[$equal]</td></tr>$editmode[$equal]
```

Comment: Hey @Misunderstood, thanks for the reply. I'm currently working on implementing this into the page and will let you know.

Comment: So I threw the code in and I'm getting a "can't currently handle this request" in the browser. At first, I thought it was because of the missing "(" here: `if $file == '.' || $file == '..' || $entry == "Blank-Package")` so I went ahead added it. It made no difference. Here is the complete page: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/WObqni4G

Comment: I made an update.